# Can I put formula numbers in a question or an answer?

Tags: support, mathjax

Suppose I'm writing a question like

blah blah blah $$a=0$$ blah blah blah

I want to put (1) at the very right of the line that has $a=0$. Can I do that?

Comment: The answer [Tags & References](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/11491#11491) in MathJax tutorial has some details on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

blah blah blah

$$a=0 \tag{1}$$

blah blah blah

---

To get the above, use `\tag{*insert number/label here*}` at the end of the formula, like the following:

---

blah blah blah

`$$a= 0\tag{1}$$`

blah blah blah

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask you one more question? How do you put those horizontal lines between paragraphs?

Comment: You can do that by writing a dashed line `---------` (doesn't have to be long like the entire width of the page, just a handful of -'s).  Also, when you are composing a post, you'll see a menu along the top, the menu with images.  One shows grey lines, above and below, separated by a dashed line.  Clicking on that will give you a horizontal line, like you see in my post.

Comment: To get the equation number in math format use `tag{$1$}`  ... for example if you want the tag to be $1'$ you will need the dollar signs there.